# CodeIgniter: Way to use variable across entire site?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a variable that has the first URL segment. I want to use this as a class on the `body` tag. It will mainly be used for setting links in my navigation as being active. Is there a way that I can create this variable in one place and use it in all of my controllers? Its not that big of a problem to set it in all of my controllers but I'd like to keep my code as clean as possible. This is what I have in my controllers right now:

```
$url_segment = $this->uri->rsegment_array(); //get array of url segment strings
$data['url_segment'] = $url_segment[1]; //gets string of first url segment
```

Is there a way to only have the code above ONCE in my app, instead of inside all of my controllers? If so where should I place it?

Comment: youre trying to avoid just doing it in a view file?  I usually keep a separte view file for header and footer and would just do something like this there.

Comment: What's wrong with using `$this->uri->rsegment(1)` wherever you need that particular segment?

Answer (score 3):

I'd extend `CI_Controller` with a custom subclass that includes that variable, then have all the actual controllers extend that. CodeIgniter makes it easy - just create application/core/MY_Controller.php containing something along these lines:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    private $cached_url_seg;
    function MY_Controller() {
        parent::construct();
        $url_segment = $this->uri->rsegment_array(); //get array of url segment strings
        $this->cached_url_seg = $url_segment[1]; //gets string of first url segment
    }
}
```

And then change your controllers to extend `MY_Controller`.

You'll still have to add it to $data in each individual controller, but I suppose if you wanted you could add `private $data` to `MY_Controller`, too.

Comment: `$cached_url_seg` variable should be `$this->cached_url_seg`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider making a 1 time library file, with all features you want to be globally accessable, then in your autoload.php add this library there so it initializes automatically..

```
class my_global_lib {

  protected $CI;
  public $segment;

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance(); 

    // Do your code here like:
    $this->segment = $this->CI->uri->segment(1);

    // Any other things you want to have accessable by default could go here

  }

}
```

This would allow you to call this from your controller like so

```
echo $this->my_global_lib->segment;
```

does this help?